# How do you supply multiple TxnIDs to a QBXML request?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

From my understand there's only 1 request where you can pass a TxnIDList and that's [TimeTrackingQuery](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/timetrackingquery). The XML i'm trying to pass is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <TimeTrackingQueryRq requestID="1"  iterator="Start">
            <TxnID >9-1673543531</TxnId>
            <TxnID >A-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >7-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >8-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >B-1673543531</TxnID>
        </TimeTrackingQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

But this gives me an error of: `There is a missing element: &quot;MaxReturned&quot;.`
Using the SDK validator, this query is marked as valid, however and looking at the documentation it says I can either supply a repeating element of `TxnID` **or** a `MaxReturned` value with nested elements.

If i also pass it a `MaxReturned` element along with the TxnIDs it will complain that the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <TimeTrackingQueryRq requestID="1"  iterator="Start">
            <TxnID >9-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >A-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >7-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >8-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >B-1673543531</TxnID>
            <MaxReturned>1000</MaxReturned>
        </TimeTrackingQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Lastly, if I close off the `TimeTrackingQueryRq` tag and re-open it and just include `MaxReturned` in the second tag, it will say it's valid XML but will return the same errors as the first request. Example of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <TimeTrackingQueryRq requestID="1"  iterator="Start">
            <TxnID >9-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >A-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >7-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >8-1673543531</TxnID>
            <TxnID >B-1673543531</TxnID>
        </TimeTrackingQueryRq>
        <TimeTrackingQueryRq requestID="1">
            <MaxReturned>1000</MaxReturned>
        </TimeTrackingQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

So either I don't know how to pass a TxnIDList or I don't know how to properly read the documentation and provided schema. Any help or examples of how to properly construct this request is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem, but with `ItemInventoryQuery`, passing `FullName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Just remove the attribute `iterator="Start"`.
Here is a [reference](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/exploring-the-quickbooks-desktop-sdk/query-requests-and-responses) about it.